# Why are record classes immutable by default, but record structs are not, in C#?

Tags: c#, immutability, record

I was taught that structs should almost always be immutable, so this unusual behaviour of record classes vs. record structs threw me off guard.

Using a record class...

```cs
record class Person(string FirstName, string LastName);
Person p = new("John", "Smith");
p.FirstName = "Jack" // Not allowed!
```

Using a record struct...

```cs
record struct Person(string FirstName, string LastName);
Person p = new("John", "Smith");
p.FirstName = "Jack" // Fine!
```

Using a readonly record struct...

```cs
readonly record struct Person(string FirstName, string LastName);
Person p = new("John", "Smith");
p.FirstName = "Jack" // Now allowed!
```

Why are *non `readonly`* record structs mutable by default, and why doesn't the same behaviour apply for record classes?

Edit: I guess what I'm asking here is, why is the syntax... weird?

For example, it would seem more logical like:

- `record class` - **mutable** reference type with value semantics.
- `readonly record class` - **immutable** reference type with value semantics.
- `record struct` - **mutable** value type with value semantics.
- `readonly record struct` - **immutable** value type with value semantics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the *positional* syntax for defining a `record class`, it's properties are immutable

```
record class Point(int X, int Y);
```

It defaults to having property accessory of `{get; init;}`

If you declare this in a traditional way (without positional parameters), you can specify your property accessors:

```
record class Point
{
    int X {get; set;}
    int Y {get; set;}
}
```

You can mix and match these two styles, but bear in mind that if you provide any positional parameters, they will become the parameters on the auto implemented constructor, and any other properties will not be set.

I realise this doesn't actually answer the question as to why this behaviour exists, I'm just hoping that people that read this won't come away with the conclusion that `record class` is immutable.

Answer (score 14):

Taken directly from a Microsoft MVP Engineer İlkay İlknur:

> Most of the generated code looks similar to the record classes.
> However, there is one difference between record structs and record
> classes. The generated properties in record structs are mutable by
> default. The reason behind this decision was to be consistent with
> tuples. Tuples are like anonymous record structs with similar
> features. On the other hand, struct mutability does not carry the same
> level of concern as class mutability does. That's why the C# team
> decided to make record struct properties mutable by default. However,
> if you need immutable record structs, you can use the readonly
> keyword.

[record-structs-in-csharp](https://www.ilkayilknur.com/record-structs-in-csharp-10#:%7E:text=Tuples%20are%20like%20anonymous%20record,struct%20properties%20mutable%20by%20default.)